# Android : How to make a library that I've written be compilable through gradle?

Tags: android, compilation, gradle

I often make use of third party opensource libraries that are compiled through gradle. For example, in the gradle.build file I would write:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
```

in order to enable me to use the picasso library.

I've now written my own new standalone library and I want the public to be able to access it through gradle by typing in something similar to the above in their gradle.build files. What are the steps to enable such functionality?

Comment: Gradle is so damned mysterious...

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile right now. But there's a blog post on it.

http://felipecsl.com/blog/2013/12/06/publishing-an-android-library-to-maven-central/